# converting iwov xml to standard xml using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I want to convert it from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record name="iwov" type="content">
    <item name="locator">
        <value>
            <item name="storeLocator">
                <value>
                    <item name="StoreID">
                        <value>test1</value>
                    </item>
                    <item name="StoreName">
                        <value>mytest</value>
                    </item>
                </value>
            </item>
        </value>
    </item>
</record>
```

To using perl can someone throw some idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locator>
    <storeLocator>
        <StoreID>test1</StoreID>
        <StoreName>mytest</StoreName>
    </storeLocator>
</locator>
```

Comment: Show your code/effort/idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;

use XML::Twig;

my( $in, $expected)= do { local $/="\n\n"; <DATA> };

my $result= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { item   => sub { $_->set_tag( $_->att( 'name'))->del_att( 'name'); },
                                              value  => sub { $_->erase; },
                                              record => sub { $_->erase; },   
                                             },
                            pretty_print => 'indented',
                          )
                     ->parse( $in)
                     ->sprint;

is( $result, $expected);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record name="iwov" type="content">
    <item name="locator">
        <value>
            <item name="storeLocator">
                <value>
                    <item name="StoreID">
                        <value>test1</value>
                    </item>
                    <item name="StoreName">
                        <value>mytest</value>
                    </item>
                </value>
            </item>
        </value>
    </item>
</record>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locator>
  <storeLocator>
    <StoreID>test1</StoreID>
    <StoreName>mytest</StoreName>
  </storeLocator>
</locator>
```

Comment: how to print the same to a file ?

Comment: @susheel use the `print` or the `print_to_file` methods on the XML::Twig object, see http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/quick_ref.html for a quick overview of the module

Comment: my $file="C:\\temp\\iwovtoxml.txt"; 
open(READ,"<$file") or print "file not found";
open(OUT," >$file") or print "file not found";

i tried to print(OUT)

Comment: did you try `print_to_file( $file)`? otherwise you should write `open( my $out, '>', $file) or die "cannot create '$file'": $!"; $twig->print( $out);` Using lexical file handles and 3-arg open is the current best practice.  Read the perl docs about `open`. You may need to use an IO layer if your data is not pure ASCII, that's also explained in the docs.